# is there any way to access a class instance in other cs file?

Tags: c#

I just defined a static class instance to realize this, but my program has some bugs, I'm wondering is that the static instance cause the bug.
so is there any good way to access a class instance in other cs file?

My code is below:

```
public class AdvCANIO
{ 
   private IntPtr hDevice;                                                           
   //Device handle
   private IntPtr orgWriteBuf = IntPtr.Zero;                                         
   // Fields
   private Win32Events events;
   private Win32Ovrlap ioctlOvr;
   .....
    public AdvCANIO()
    {
      hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        .......
    }
    ~AdvCANIO()
    {
       if (hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
       {
          AdvCan.CloseHandle(hDevice);
          Thread.Sleep(100);
          ........
          Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpCommandBuffer);     
          hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
       }
    }
```

xx.cs

```
public static AdvCANIO Device ;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Device = new AdvCANIO();
}
```

yy.cs

```
xx.Device.hDevice... ;  //Device is the class instance in xx file.
```

Comment: "now i just defined a static class instance" - can't do that. It either static or instance

Comment: @T.S.  i just do that in my code ,public static AdvCANIO Device ; my english is bad, don't know how to express this appropriately

Comment: Are they in the same namespace?  In the same class?  The full name of a class includes the namespace and parent class(s).  It is the same as Net Library when you have System.Data.SqlClient. System is a namespace.  Data is a namespace.  And SqlClient is a namespace.  SqlClient has classes like SqlDataAdapter.  Your project has similar namespaces and classes.

Comment: You can not use `xx.Device.hDevice`

Comment: @jdweng   that's a dll library without namespace,my project use the same namespace,i can use xx.Device.hDevice without error or warning hint

Comment: You are overwriting the value of Device any time you create a new MainWindow since it is static. Perhaps that is your problem. Not sure what xx and yy are. I suppose they are really supposed to be the class names like MainWindow.Device which you CAN access. But if xx is a variable name then no you can't.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33  thanks, you're right. any other way to do this without define a static variable.